# What is the address for internal storage on browser?

Tags: browser, storage

If `file:///sdcard/` is the access address for the SD card, then what is the address for internal storage on my HTC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably won't be able to access much of your internal storage via the web browser. The URL you mentioned, `file:///sdcard/`, consists of two parts: the protocol (`file://`), and the path (`/sdcard/`). So basically, you just have to change the path accordingly. You can check with a file manager what the path to the desired destination is.